# Microsoft Word VSTO AddIn not able to write a file to the file system - access denied

Tags: c#, .net, vsto, office-addins

I am working on a `Microsoft Word Add In` using VSTO, and the Add In works properly on my development system. But when I install it on another system, it is not able to create a file on the file system and throws the following error:

`Access to the path XYZ is denied`.

This exception is thrown when the following line of code is executed:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(Constants.temporaryTemplateFile, schemaEntity.TemplateFile);
```

The Microsoft Word is running as a User which is Administrator. In the task manager, the `WINWORD.EXE` shows the user as `xyz` which is an Administrator.

Any suggestions how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

go to folder than want create file in. then in right click **properties** options on **security** tab add **everyone** type user, give all access to everyone.
[image]
after do this test your add-ins again, if result is ok you know that problem in accessing and you can find way for this problem...